# get access_token for a Twitter application which does not have a callback URL using Python

Tags: python, oauth, twitter

I have created an application with its "callback URL" field as blank. I want to programatically use access_token function of oauth endpoint (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/oauth/access_token) and fetch oauth_token and oauth_token_secret.

I am able to do this from my browser my going to my applications and then generating the access token by click of a button. However, I want to do this automatically via a python program. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/oauth/access_token states that "callback URL" is a mandatory flied. Keeping it blank is not working as results in "401 Unauthorized Failed to validate oauth signature and token" response.

I do not want to use any twitter API wrappers or oauth library.

I have tried the following code -

```
    import httplib
    import uuid
    from time import time

    host = 'api.twitter.com'
    url = "/oauth/request_token"
    req = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host)
    req.putrequest("GET", url)
    req.putheader("Host", host)

    uid = uuid.uuid4()
    req.putheader("oauth_consumer_key" , consumer_key)
    req.putheader("OAuth oauth_nonce" , uid.hex)
    req.putheader("oauth_signature_method" , "HMAC-SHA1")
    req.putheader("oauth_timestamp" , str(time.time()))
    req.putheader("oauth_version" , "1.0")
    req.putheader("oauth_callback" , "")
    req.putheader("oauth_signature" , consumer_secret)

    req.endheaders()        
    resp = req.getresponse()
    data = resp.read()
    print resp.status, resp.reason
    print data
```

This returns "401 Unauthorized. Failed to validate oauth signature and token"

How do I access the my oauth_token and oauth_token_secret for the application which I have created?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399978/getting-started-with-twitter-oauth2-python) - if you want to implement the entire oAuth2 handshake.
Otherwise I am using [tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy), which will take care of that for you.